# Socket server on different port and Client on different port

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am developing a private chat application. My Server side code(NodeJs + Express + Socket.io) is running on port 7000. And my client side code(AngularJs) is running on port 8000.

When I am trying to connect my socket client(running in port 8000) to socket server(which is running on port 7000), I am getting 404, which is obvious.

I have following questions related to this:-

1. I am now unable to figure out how I can make Socket client @ port 8000 listen/get connect to socket server @ port 7000.
2. Will there be any impact on all this configuration if tomorrow in production I will introduce Ngnix which will be running on port 80?

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: What does _"my client is running on port 8000"_ mean?

Comment: Client means AngularJs+  HTML's + CSS etc. And entire server side code is running on port 7000. Server side code is exposed as Rest services for client. And to keep separation of concern we have kept entire client side as separation code base running on port 8000.

Comment: You're just repeating your question. What does it mean to have a "client running on a port"? That is not a thing, at least not in TCP concepts (well you _could_ bind a client socket to a port, but you should not want to in this situation). Perhaps show some relevant code.

Comment: By client , I mean AngularJS + HTML related code.

Comment: I'm not asking what you mean by client. I'm asking what you mean by _"Socket client @ port 8000 listen"_. A client socket does not listen.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Instead of include socket.io in your HTML as :-

You can also include it as